# SMBClient, cannot copy or print any file

Tags: linux, windows, samba, smb

I'm connecting to a SMB share using the following command :

```
smbclient -U domain\\user "\\\ip\share"
```

I can list directory files using dir command or get file informations

```
smb: \server\> allinfo file.ext
altname: file
create_time:    Thu Nov 30 10:35:28 2017 CET
access_time:    Mon Aug 13 17:14:32 2018 CEST
write_time:     Wed Sep 12 11:04:16 2018 CEST
change_time:    Fri Jul 10 18:33:11 2020 CEST
attributes: A (20)
stream: [::$DATA], 1884160 bytes
```

But whenever i'm trying to print the file content, or copy file locally I get an **Error opening local file** response

```
smb: \server\> print file.ext
Error opening local file file.ext
```

The SMB server is a Windows server host. Permissions are set correctly and I don't have restrictions when using windows client with same user.